# Syslog-ng not flushing output to python program

Tags: python, syslog-ng

I have set up syslog-ng to tail a file and forward each new event to python script which will process it.

My syslog-ng.conf looks like this -

```
source s_src {
   file("/var/log/xyz.log" flags(no_parse);
};

destination d_dest {
   program("python -u /home/user1/processlog.py" flush_lines(1) flags(no_multi_line));
};

log { source(s_src); destination(d_dest); };
```

And processlog.py just contains

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

f1 = open('success.txt', 'a')

while 0 < 1:
  try:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    f1.write(line)

  except Exception, e:
    f = open('/tmp/error.txt','ab')
    f.write(e)
    f.close()
    exit(0)
```

This script works prefectly fine from command line. Takes each input and writes to success.txt.

Syslog-ng also starts but does not forward the event to python program above. It starts the program though.

```
ps -ef| grep processlog
root      6242  6236  0 13:00 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c python -u /home/user1/processlog.py
root      6244  6242  0 13:00 ?        00:00:00 python -u /home/user1/processlog.py
```

I have checked all permissions too. But whenever new event happens in xyz.log, it is not getting forwarded to python script, which i am testing via writing to success.txt

Any leads are highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know it is not forwarding?  It will not appear in `success.txt` immediately because of buffering.  If you want that, then call `f1.flush()` after `f1.write(line)`.

Comment: I added f1.flush() as you said, but it still does not appear in the success.txt. My purpose is to test if the event is getting processed immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run syslog-ng in foreground mode with enabled debug messages

`syslog-ng -Fedtv`

Perhaps you will get information about why the program destination doesn't get the messages.

By the way, is it possible that the syslog-ng read this file once?

In this case you should delete the persist file (var/syslog-ng.persist) to force the syslog-ng to read this file from beginning.